# simpletransformers: size mismatch for classifier.weight and classifier.bias even after providing correct arguments with simpletransformers library

Tags: python, named-entity-recognition, simpletransformers

I'm using **simpletransformers** library for fine-tuning a BERT model for Named Entity Recognition (NER) on a custom dataset which is having 13 distinct entities.
Even after providing `model_args.labels_list`, the `NERModel()` produce the following error.

```
RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for BertForTokenClassification:
    size mismatch for classifier.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([9, 768]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([13, 768]).
    size mismatch for classifier.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([9]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([13]).
```

Sample code:

```
from simpletransformers.ner import NERModel, NERArgs

model_args = NERArgs()
model_args.labels_list = ["ENT1", "ENT2", "ENT3", "ENT4", "ENT5", "ENT6", "ENT7", "ENT8", "ENT9", "ENT10", "ENT11", "ENT12", "ENT13"]  # this list is having thirteen entities from my dataset

model = NERModel(
    "bert",
    "dslim/bert-base-NER",
    args=model_args,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I updated my simpletransformers and it solved the problem.